# Enable/disable RabbitMQ plugin via HTTP REST API?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to enable/disable a RabbitMQ plugin via the REST API?

E.g. I want to do this:

```
rabbitmq-plugins disable rabbit_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbit_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbit_shovel_management
```

I don't see anything mentioned here:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.11.13/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported at this time.